# Как добавить результат fetch в store Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, promise, fetch

Суть результата - обычный вывод информации о товаре на страницу, для чего отправляется запрос на бэкенд.
async function getData(){

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8888", {
    method: 'POST',
  header: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
body: JSON.stringify({action: 1})
})
return response.json()}

export async function goods(){
    const data = await getData();
    return data;}
```

store.js

```
export const goodsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'goods',
    initialState: { 
        goods:  goods()
    },
    reducers: {}
})
```

Вывод результата в консоль:
[image: результат вывода в консоль]

Как вывести результат промиса?
Понимаю, что возможно не дотягивает знаний по промисам, но уже уперся как баран...

Answer (score 0):

В `initialState` нельзя использовать асинхронные функции.

Чтобы добавить в стейт результат, получаемый асинхронно с сервера, нужно использовать `createAsyncThunk`:

```
export const fetchGoods = createAsyncThunk("goods/fetch", async () => goods());
```

и добавить его в `createSlice` в блок `extraReducers`:

```
export const goodsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "goods",
  initialState: {
    goods: []
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchGoods.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.goods = action.payload;
    });
  }
});
```

После этого можно использовать `fetchGoods` в `useEffect` для первоначальной загрузки:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchGoods } from "./goodsSlice";

// Дальше внутри компонента
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchGoods());
}, [dispatch]);
```

Ссылка на codesandbox с рабочим примером - https://codesandbox.io/s/red-silence-uf9fg

Документация Redux Toolkit - https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#async-requests-with-createasyncthunk

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало!